# DELETE if NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

First table: **f** *(a,b,c,d are the columns)*

```
a  |  b  |  c  |   d
1  |  2  |  3  |   4
5  |  6  |  7  |   8
9  |  10 |  11 |   12
13 |  14 |  15 |   16
```

Second table: **s** *(a,b,c,d are the columns)*

```
a  |  b  |  c  |   d
5  |  6  |  c  |   d
9  |  10 |  c  |   d
20 |  5  |  c  |   d
```

---

I need to delete the **not equal** rows (between **f** to **s**) from the **f** table only

so the new **f** table  will look like that:

```
a  |  b  |  c  |   d
5  |  6  |  7  |   8
9  |  10 |  11 |   12
```

How to know if two rows are **equal**? (i need to delete what is **not equal**)

If `f.a=s.a AND f.b=s.b` the lines are equal, and i need this line to stay.

How could I build it with Sql only? All I tried to do, not worked for me.

---

here is example for source that i tried to do:

```
DELETE FROM f WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM f inner join s on (f.a=s.a and f.b=s.b) 
)
```

Comment: Where does 5,7,c,d come from in the desired result? Also, why is the 9,10,11,12 row modified to 9,10,c,d?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i edit the new f table in the question. the c,d was a mistake.

Comment: Typo also that 5,6,7,8 remains when there is only a 5,7,c,d in s?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i dont really care about the c,d columns. to know if rows equal, i need to check the a,b columns only (in f table and als in s table)

Comment: Yes, but 5,6 is not equal to 5,7 so the row should be deleted, no?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you right, it was a mistake, i change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `DELETE`/`LEFT JOIN`, which in MySQL would look like;

```
DELETE f 
FROM f
LEFT JOIN s 
  ON f.a = s.a AND f.b = s.b
WHERE s.a IS NULL
```

If there is no row that matches between f and s, s.a will be NULL in the result and the corresponding row in f will therefore be deleted.

[An SQLfiddle to test with.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/569177/1)

And, as always, always back up your data before running potentially destructive SQL from random people on the Internet on it.

Comment: Thank you. This saved my bacon. Many other answers on this kind of question but this is the only thing that worked in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want without the join on the subquery:

```
DELETE FROM f
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM s on f.a = s.a and f.b = s.b) ;
```

Comment: Dear Gordon, can you please point me to some tutorials for sub queries where the tables join themselves.

Comment: @Vish . . . This is called a correlated subquery.  You can start with the MySQL documentation on this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but it didnt do what i need. it didnt delete the not equal rows from the f table

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand correlated queries, however, what do you call queries like this http://imgur.com/oLNKOW9.

Comment: @ldoroni . . . This answers the question in the text and fixes your query.  Your sample data doesn't make any sense.  For instance, why does 5/6 stay in the data when it is not in `s`.  As for your second question, that is a poorly written `join` using implicit `join` syntax that has been out-of-date for 20 years.  (Allowed, but explicit joins are much preferred.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff i edit the question, i had a mistake in the s table. right now it 5,6,.. and not 5,7,...

Answer (score 0):

You can use MERGE feature, it's more faster.

You script will look like this:

```
MERGE f as target
USING s as source 
ON (f.a=s.a and f.b=s.b) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target
THEN DELETE 
;
```

Comment: Does MERGE work in that way in MySQL?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist